# Scala: Chain multiple functions with Try[T] as the return type

Tags: scala, functional-programming, try-catch

I am new to functional programming in Scala and am working on a module where each operators (class instance/object) are chained together. The operators has only one function and that returns a Try[T]. I'm looking for a more readable way of chaining them together.

```
trait Mapper {
    def map(in: T): Try[T]
}

trait Reducer {
    def reduce(in: T): Try[T]
}

trait Grouper {
    def group(in: T, batchSize: int): Try[T]
}
```

Lets just say I have created the implementations for these traits. Now in my main function, I can do something like

```
object MyApp extends App {
    val mapper: Mapper = ...
    val reducer: Reducer = ...
    val grouper: Grouper = ...  

    def run(): Try[Unit] = {
        val inp: T = ...
        mapper.map(inp) match {
            case Success(x) => reducer.reduce(x) match {
                case Success(y) => grouper.group(x) match {
                    case Success(z) => ..// some other function call
                    case Failure(e) => throw e
                }
                case Failure(e) => throw e
                }
           case Failure(e) => throw e
        }
    }

   run()
}
```

Is there a way, I can avoid all these Success, Failure pattern matching and do it in a better way?

Comment: This is just basic `flatMap` chaining, any basic tutorial about **Scala** should have covered this. It may be good to study a little bit about the language, the stdlib and how to use it before diving deep into trying to write code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple and typical `for-comprehension` is the case:

```
def run(): Try[Unit] = {
    val inp: T = ...
    for {
     mapResult <- mapper.map(inp)
     reduceresult <- reducer.reduce(mapResult)
     groupResult <- grouper.group(x)
    } yield ()
}
```

You can find lot's of learning materials about this topic in internet, but essentially this is syntax sugar over `flatMap`, `map`, `withFilter` and `foreach` for cases like yours.